# JS append to child only works on some webpages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Context: I have a Chrome extension that is not an app where `chrome.extension.isInstalled` (or whatever that code is) will work. Therefore I'm detecting the presence of whether or not my extension is installed by having the extension append a blank div into the webpage. This way, I can check if that div is present, and if so, not allow user to install again.

The problem is, both these variations of code below:

```
var isInstalled = document.createElement('div');
isInstalled.id = 'extension-is-installed';
document.body.appendChild(isInstalled);

document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='extension-is-installed-2'>"
```

Work on some pages and not others. They work on Google, REI, etc. but not on eBay, Amazon, etc. Incidentally, the one page I need it to work on http://www.projectborrow.com, it does not.

Any thoughts on why? I included my site above so that someone can try to make the append-ment work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `manifest.json` file for the Chrome Extension, you have to specify which websites the extention will operate on. Then in the code for the actual extension itself, you need to specify how the extension will operate on each site.